# iterm2 / bash keyboard commands -- option-tab and tab-tab

Tags: bash, terminal, iterm

I've been unable to find documentation for two keyboard shortcuts in iterm2 or bash (not sure which is doing it), namely <kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd> and <kbd>tab</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd>. When I use them, I get a question, for example,

```
Display all 192 possibilities (y or n)?
```

for <kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd>, or

```
Display all 3929 possibilities (y or n)?
```

for <kbd>tab</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd>

When I say `y`, I get lists of things I may have typed recently, or things that look like files on my path.  Because of the large numbers of things, it's difficult to tell exactly what's going on.

I looked at the iTerm2 documentation and I did a few searches for "option-tab" and various cheat sheets, but the answer wasn't forthcoming.

Comment: It's the bash auto completion. If you start entering something on the command line and hit <tab><tab> you'll see the results are fewer.  Try `echo $<tab><tab>`, you should get a list of variables.

Comment: What do you get as output if you type `Ctrl-v` `Option-tab` in your shell?

Comment: @EtanReisner I get `^[` (looks like `Ctrl` `left-bracket`, then, if I press `Enter`, `-bash: command not found`. Still no good idea of what's going on.

Comment: Option-tab works the same as tab for me; for you it looks like it generates ASCII 033 (escape). This is likely an iterm2 configuration issue, unrelated to `bash`.

Comment: I don't know why `escape` `escape` (assuming that's what you meant given what `option-tab` generates) would generate a different list of possible completions than tab (it doesn't seem to here).

Comment: @EtanReisner yup, i double checked -- I get a much shorter list of things with `option`-`tab`, and they're not the names of files on my path, but rather look like command-line arguments that I've typed recently, things like `--upgrade` and `"my recent git commit message"` and `../foo/bar/baz/qux`.

Comment: @chepner if I directly type `esc` `esc`, I don't get anything useful. My `option` `tab` shortcut must be doing something else than aliasing directly to `esc` `esc`

Comment: Does `esc` `tab` `esc` `tab` get you what `option-tab` does?